# so, Do we say "Good Affordable hotel" or "Affordable Good hotel"?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, adjective-order

A native American teacher said, we have to say "**Good Affordable hotel**".

[This page](https://www.espressoenglish.net/order-of-adjectives-in-english/) mentions the order of Adjectives in English

> Opinion
>
> Size
>
> Shape
>
> Age
>
> Color
>
> Nationality/Origin
>
> Material
>
> Purpose

Ex: good (opinion) small (size) shoes.

But the site did not say how we order 2 adjectives of a same kind.

"**Good Affordable hotel**" or "**Affordable Good hotel**" since both "**Good**" & "**Affordable**" are opinion-based adjectives?

Comment: In AmE it would be normal to say or hear **good, affordable hotel**, but not *affordable, good hotel*. I can't document the reason, and I look forward to learning from the answers.

Comment: I agree with this page, that price can either come first as a determiner/quantity, or last (adding price as another 'p' after purpose.)   http://steve-dyson.blogspot.com/2014/11/osascomp-applied-analysis.html

Comment: You can say either.  If you place **affordable** first ("affordable good hotel"), it puts a little more emphasis on "affordable" than it would have in "good, affordable hotel", perhaps if you've been recommended several good hotels all of which are exorbitantly priced. *Aren't there any affordable good hotels?*  The more usual phrasing is "good, affordable hotel".  *I am looking for a good, affordable car*.

Comment: I think the best advice would be to not make this construction at all. "Good" is practically meaningless if used to describe a hotel.

Comment: An "affordable hotel" is commonly seen as a "category" of hotel (in a similar way to "4-star hotel") because it is something you would commonly search for, so in general the opinion "good" would modify the category "affordable hotel".

Comment: As an aside, the term ["native American"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States) is more commonly used to refer to the indigenous people of America, who are also sometimes referred to as "American Indians", rather than to refer to someone who was born/raised in the USA.

Comment: That order rule is good if you are starting with a collection of adjectives and have no basis for assigning an order, so it is a choice of random selection vs. the rule.  However, if you have a specific priority, meaning, or context, that may provide a better basis for the order.  Boatseller's answer is an example.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the order implies set you create first.

> Good Affordable hotel

Expresses that you are looking for an affordable hotel, that is also good.

> Affordable Good hotel

Expresses you are looking for a good hotel, that is also affordable.

Comment: I think you mean "closeness to the noun" not "order".